# Find Average Using Two Conditions (with Different Data Types, number of days and currency)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I was given a case describing projects -- their budgets, schedule, etc.

I've identified those that are over budget and over schedule ('Personal Findings' cell B14)

```
=COUNTIFS('NYC P&R'!I:I,">0",'NYC P&R'!N:N,">0")
```

Now I need to find the average of each using this condition -- *Of those projects that are over budget and over schedule, what are the average number of days over schedule? What is the average over budget?*

For the average number of days (with conditions), I've tried this input:

```
=AVERAGEIFS('NYC P&R'!E:E,">0",'NYC P&R'!N:N,">0)")
```

But I'm then met with:
AVERAGE​IFS expect all arguments after position 3 to be in pairs.

I don't know if I'm inputting the data wrong, using the function wrong, or need an entirely different function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

[Link to Sheet Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NuhHCZNnqpzpKR90aKBmarphGmdENe1T/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=113266681769336951800&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not specifying [AverageIfs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256534?hl=en) first parameter (`AVERAGE_RANGE`). This should be the range where the numeric values exist. This also happens to be a column for one of your `criteria_range` conditions, which I think is where you got tripped up. It looks like you tried to use your `CountIfs` syntax, but `CountIfs` doesn't require any calculations beyond true/false, so it doesn't need the initial parameter for numeric data.

For days your formula should be:

```
=AVERAGEIFS('NYC P&R'!E:E,'NYC P&R'!E:E,">0",'NYC P&R'!N:N,">0")
```

For Amount:

```
=AVERAGEIFS('NYC P&R'!N:N,'NYC P&R'!E:E,">0",'NYC P&R'!N:N,">0")
```

#### Other Options

`AverageIfs` is probably the most practical approach, but here are a couple other options that populate both of your desired outcomes. You could put either of these formulas in any cell and it would populate both a header and the two averages (so four cells total).

```
={"Average Days","Average Cost";
Average(filter('NYC P&R'!E:E,('NYC P&R'!E:E>0)*('NYC P&R'!N:N>0))),
Average(filter('NYC P&R'!N:N,('NYC P&R'!E:E>0)*('NYC P&R'!N:N>0)))}
```

As the other answer mentioned, [the query function](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/google-sheets-query-sql/) could be used this way as well...

```
=QUERY('NYC P&R'!E:N, "SELECT AVG(E), AVG(N) WHERE E > 0 and N > 0
LABEL AVG(E) 'Average Days', AVG(N) 'Average Cost'", 1)
```

Both formulas would return:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Consider learning the `QUERY` formula. It is powerful, and opens up plenty of possibilities. It uses the [Google Visualization API Query Language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage).

For your specific requirement, the formula would look something like:

```
=QUERY('NYC P&R'!A:P, "SELECT AVG(N) WHERE E > 0 and N > 0 LABEL AVG(N) ''", -1)
```

It returns average of column `N` (total days overdue) for all entries that have a `> 0` value in columns `E` (design schedule overdue) and `N`.

Of course, you could use different columns in the condition based on your requirement, and there's a fairly exhaustive list of comparison operators for all data types you'd typically work with.

The `LABEL AVG(N) ''` part at the end is to get rid of the unnecessary (depending on the use case) heading that comes back with the result.